# How to stop Handler Definitely?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a project using Arduino and Android Java, and I built a robot that follows automatically a specific map, written by the robot owner.

To run the map automatically, the user must specify an hour to start and an hour to stop the robot from following the mapping, and he needs to specify an interval, because the map will run from time to time.

All this code is running in a Background service.

I created an Handler to check if the current hour is equal to some of the hours stored in an arraylist. My application starts this function when it founds a match:

```
public void startEvent(String getMapping, String getReplayInterval, String getReplayHourEnd, final int getRobotId, final String getMapName) {

  eventHandler = new Handler();

        eventHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                if (count < getMoves.length) {

                    String[] getMoveObject = getMoves[count++].split("/");

                    String getMove = getMoveObject[0];
                    String getObject = getMoveObject[1];

                    moveRobot(getMove, Boolean.valueOf(getObject), getRobotId, getMapName);

                    delay = 1000;
                }

                if (count == getMoves.length) {

                    moveRobot("stop", false, getRobotId, getMapName);
                    count = 0;

                    //Interval hour
                    delay = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(t);

                }

                if (hour.equals(splitEndHour[0]) && minute.equals(splitEndHour[1]) && second.equals(splitEndHour[2])) {

                    //Stop the handler
                    moveRobot("stop", false, getRobotId, getMapName);
                    eventHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(this);


                }

                eventHandler.postDelayed(this, delay);


            }


        }, 1000);

}
```

My issue here is when I try to stop the handler when the current hour reaches the hour that the user choose to stop the robot from running the mapping.

I tried to use:

```
eventHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(this);
```

But the code keeps running, what do I need to change on my code to definitely remove stop the handler and clean all messages?

Thank you.

Comment: You're unconditionally calling ` eventHandler.postDelayed(this, delay);` every loop. So it doesn't matter if you remove the callbacks. You're still making it do it again.

Comment: Thank you, I solved this problem by adding a boolean that returns false when the hour is equal to the hour that the user choose to stop the mapping.